# Get Values from Listbox for if functions

Tags: vb.net, listbox

Hey guys very new here.

Have a listbox that gets account names from a specific game server using this command line

```
Dim apikeyinfo As APIKeyInfo = api.getApiKeyInfo()
lstbxCharacters.DataSource = apikeyinfo.Characters
```

this code gets all the characters in a single account by displaying it in a listbox.

Now i would like to reference a character from the lisbox but not sure how

Any method such as Listbox.Get to get the value and compare it with something else?

Thanks

Comment: Just read from Listbox.Datasource

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like

```
lstbxCharacters.SelectedItem
```

**Update**

To read the data from the listbox I think there are multiple ways (Assuming that it is readable).

-> Usually listbox display strings, so it should work to read to a string variable

```
Dim a_string as Strin = lstbxCharacters.SelectedItem
```

also you may like to add a small check before, assuring that an Item is currently selected:

```
If lstbxCharacters.SelectedIndex < 0 then return
```

This jumps out of current sub if no item is selected

And finally, to read the first entry, you can also do it this way:

```
a_string = lstbxCharacters.Items(0)
```

if it returns objects, then instead of accessing the object directly, it may work to do

```
a_string = lstbxCharacters.Items(0).ToString
```

(most objects allow a .ToString() Function )

**Here two ideas for different solutions:**

1. As a user commented, you could access the DataSource directly + the information which listIndex was selected. But if you do so, then maybe it is more easy (if you need to access it anyways, to go with solution 2)
2. Create a variable of type list(Of some_object) and fill it with the data from the datasource. It will take some time to do this, but if you define for the class some_object a function ToString, then you can fill all objects directly to the lstbxCharacters, and access them without any worries, by doing   CType(lstbxCharacters.SelectedItem, some_object)

**Update 2**
If with `reference` you mean to access further information from the datasource, then you need to build some kind of query, or set the content of the listbox in relation to another control that shows the database content (in that way the listbox lstbxCharacters would act like a filter)

Comment: I get the following message when I try to use it in a If statement. 

Any ideas? 
Warning 1 variable 'Text' conflicts with property 'Text' in the base class 'Form' and should be declared 'Shadows'

Comment: Define a variable different to 'Text'  maybe AText or _Text or sText. Compiler ist just complaining that if you try to access the _real_ Text property, then still your variable definition is accessed, since it has the same name as that other object. (As a metapher: It vanishes in the _shadow_ of the new defined object with the same name)

Comment: Hmm I see now im getting this:"Overload resolution failed because no Public '=' can be called with these arguments:"

[If lstbxCharacters.SelectedItem = "Ainge" Then
            MsgBox("Login Success")

        End If]
Problem is im not sure what kind of value is stored within that textbox from the method i called earlier... Anyway to test the value type in that listbox?

Comment: I am sorry that I try to help. I have not much experience with connecting a control directly to a DataSource. +1 your question, so hopefully someone will see it now. Also I will update my answer in the next minutes with a few ideas in what direction you can try to solve it, but it is no full solution, still requires more work, and best would be a solution from another user (that is used to access elements like that).